# Access violation error in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to run the following matlab code in matlab 2016: http://pastebin.com/q42xhMfw which uses the following C++ compiled code (compiled using mingw64 compiler): https://github.com/rajatsaxena/IISc_Neuroscience/blob/master/Miscellaneous/mexAdaptwhile.c. Compiling the C file gives me mexw64 file but when I run it, I get an Access violation error which I think is because of some issue related to compilation or address allocation cause this script works sometimes and not other times. Here is the error log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Thu Oct 27 19:40:42 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 Version 20.19.15.4444
  Host Name           : user
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 10.0 (Build 10586)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000037fa41e8  RBX = 0000000037de0300
  RCX = 0000000000089e20  RDX = fffffffffffbf1c0
  RSP = 00000000045f9d30  RBP = 0000000037f9fe60
  RSI = 0000000000000022  RDI = 0000000000000038

   R8 = 0000000000000006   R9 = 0000000000000038
  R10 = 0000000000000850  R11 = 0000000037fa40e8
  R12 = 00000000000001c0  R13 = 0000000037f5f020
  R14 = 0000000038029c80  R15 = 0000000000000048

  RIP = 00007ffbb95d1140  EFL = 00010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007ffbb95d1140 C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sachin_report\rate_maps\mexAdaptwhile.mexw64+00004416
[  1] 0x00007ffbb95d13fe C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sachin_report\rate_maps\mexAdaptwhile.mexw64+00005118 mexFunction+00000286
[  2] 0x00000000fc5f77d1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00096209 mexRunMexFile+00000129
[  3] 0x00000000fc5f6d12 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00093458 inSwapMexfileReader+00000434
[  4] 0x00000000fc5f6966 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmex.dll+00092518 mexUnlock+00004774
[  5] 0x0000000015bb5d1f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00089375 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh_impl+00000527
[  6] 0x0000000015bb5f0e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00089870 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000062
[  7] 0x0000000015bb3e15 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00081429 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000933
[  8] 0x000000001675f451 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00848977 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00049101
[  9] 0x000000001676428f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00869007 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00069131
[ 10] 0x0000000016764ef6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00872182 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00072306
[ 11] 0x0000000016766237 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00877111 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00077235
[ 12] 0x0000000016766c05 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00879621 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00079745
[ 13] 0x000000001676642f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00877615 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00077739
[ 14] 0x000000001676613a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00876858 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00076982
[ 15] 0x000000001675de5b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00843355 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00043479
[ 16] 0x000000001675bd27 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00834855 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00034979
[ 17] 0x000000001675b1c2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00831938 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00032062
[ 18] 0x00000000166aee82 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00126594
[ 19] 0x00000000166af107 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00127239
[ 20] 0x0000000015bb5e95 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00089749 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh_impl+00000901
[ 21] 0x0000000015bb5f0e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00089870 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000062
[ 22] 0x0000000015bb3e15 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00081429 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000933
[ 23] 0x00000000166e2033 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00335923
[ 24] 0x0000000016888114 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02064660 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00682852
[ 25] 0x000000001676428f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00869007 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00069131
[ 26] 0x0000000016764ef6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00872182 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00072306
[ 27] 0x0000000016766237 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00877111 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00077235
[ 28] 0x0000000016766c05 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00879621 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00079745
[ 29] 0x000000001676642f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00877615 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00077739
[ 30] 0x000000001676613a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00876858 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00076982
[ 31] 0x000000001675de5b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00843355 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00043479
[ 32] 0x000000001675bd27 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00834855 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00034979
[ 33] 0x000000001675b1c2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00831938 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_iarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00032062
[ 34] 0x00000000166e9d47 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00367943
[ 35] 0x00000000166e9681 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00366209
[ 36] 0x00000000166e9810 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00366608
[ 37] 0x000000001689d395 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02151317 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00769509
[ 38] 0x000000001689d31e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+02151198 boost::serialization::singleton<boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<boost::archive::binaryTerm_oarchive,ir::IrTree> >::get_instance+00769390
[ 39] 0x00000000166bdad1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_lxe.dll+00187089
[ 40] 0x0000000015d40241 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00787009 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 41] 0x00000000fb6056cd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00087757 mnGetPrompt+00005933
[ 42] 0x00000000fb606473 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00091251 mnParser+00001091
[ 43] 0x0000000015ab99d1   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00235985 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00025585
[ 44] 0x0000000015ab8967   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00231783 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00021383
[ 45] 0x0000000015ab89e3   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00231907 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00021507
[ 46] 0x0000000015ab92d1   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00234193 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00023793
[ 47] 0x00000000fd01ea57   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00584279 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00030535
[ 48] 0x00000000fd02b3ac   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00635820 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00082076
[ 49] 0x00000000fd018bf0   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00560112 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00006368
[ 50] 0x00000000fd02ddaa   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00646570 iqm::UserEvalPlugin::pre+00092826
[ 51] 0x00000000fcffbd07   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00441607 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::PackagedTaskPlugin+00000727
[ 52] 0x00000000fcffc35f   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00443231 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::execute+00000575
[ 53] 0x00000000fcffbd79   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00441721 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::PackagedTaskPlugin+00000841
[ 54] 0x00000000fcffc1d4   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00442836 iqm::PackagedTaskPlugin::execute+00000180
[ 55] 0x0000000015acb4a5   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00308389 mcrRegisterExternalFunction+00024629
[ 56] 0x00000000fcfd62ea   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00287466 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00069674
[ 57] 0x00000000fcfd61d7   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00287191 iqm::Iqm::setupIqmFcnPtrs+00069399
[ 58] 0x00000000fcfbbae1   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00178913 iqm::Iqm::deliver+00003409
[ 59] 0x00000000fcfbc9df   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\iqm.dll+00182751 iqm::Iqm::deliver+00007247
[ 60] 0x00000001001a14d3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01774803 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::dispatchOne+00031459
[ 61] 0x00000001001ae933 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01829171 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00005491
[ 62] 0x00000001001aeb10 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01829648 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00005968
[ 63] 0x00000001001b0665 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01836645 sysq::getCondition+00003813
[ 64] 0x00000001001b2422 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01844258 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000162
[ 65] 0x0000000015ab9d0d   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00236813 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00026413
[ 66] 0x0000000015aba3fa   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00238586 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00028186
[ 67] 0x0000000015ab1a05   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00203269 mcr_process_events+00008629
[ 68] 0x0000000015ab3462   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00210018 mcr_process_events+00015378
[ 69] 0x00000000159293be C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\MVMLocal.dll+00234430 mvm_server::inproc::LocalFactory::terminate+00071182
[ 70] 0x00000000fa93cd89   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+01101193 mvm::detail::initLocalMvmHack+00000521
[ 71] 0x00000000fa93d355   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+01102677 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000373
[ 72] 0x00000000fa93d561   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+01103201 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000897
[ 73] 0x0000000140006fd5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00028629
[ 74] 0x0000000140007661 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00030305
[ 75] 0x00007ffbc6c98102                   C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL+00098562 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000034
[ 76] 0x00007ffbc71cc5b4                      C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00378292 RtlUserThreadStart+00000052


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.32-1 **


Caught MathWorks::System::FatalException
[Please exit and restart MATLAB]>>
```

How do I sort this out, or what changes need to be made? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely one of your arrays is running out of bounds. Does it both fail and succeed with the same input parameters? Have look at when it fails, what are the boundary conditions. Debugging mex-code is painful in my experience, [`mexPrintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexprintf.html) is your friend. A common pitfall is that C/C++ are 0-index array and Matlab is 1-index.

Comment: another thing is compiling the code in matlab 2014b works but not in matlab 2016, any comments on that?
Till I then I will try to debug it

Comment: That is very strange, both 14b and 16a use the same c/c++ compiler? You should be able to use the compiled mex-function with any matlab version and would not have to compile it separately. Can you add here the matlab code I do not have access to pastebin. Maybe you are using some matlab code that behaves differently in the different versions.

Comment: here is the link to matlab script https://github.com/rajatsaxena/IISc_Neuroscience/blob/master/Miscellaneous/plotAdapBinRateMaps.m

and the data I am using
https://github.com/rajatsaxena/IISc_Neuroscience/blob/master/Miscellaneous/day1.mat

Comment: This is the code you trying to replicate in mex, right? I was asking for the code where you call your mexAdaptwhile, or maybe i missed that.

Comment: my bad here is the link https://github.com/rajatsaxena/IISc_Neuroscience/blob/master/Miscellaneous/calcAdaptive.m

Comment: Nothing jumps out that would indicate different behavior between matlab versions. maybe in the `bwdist` have a look yourself. But as I mentioned before you should not have to recompile the mex in different matlab try using the mexw64 compiled with 14b in your new 16a environment.